# Magento Payment Module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, payment-gateway

I am developing a Credit Card payment module but I am unable to get hidden values in controller. I can not use Magento CC class as my CC form is generated in Ifram from external gateway site.

My Model file

```
<?php 
  class Square_SquarePayment_Model_Paycc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
    {

protected $_code= 'squarepayment';
protected $_formBlockType = 'squarepayment/form_squarepayment';

public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl(){
    return Mage::getUrl('creditcard/payment/process', array('_secure' => true));
}



 }
 ?>
```

My Credit Card Form is

```
<ul novalidate  method="post" class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $methodCode ?>" style="display:none;">
<label>Credit Card Number <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div id="sq-card-number"></div>
<label>Card Verification Number <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div id="sq-cvv"></div>
<label>Expiration Date <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
<label>Postal Code <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
```

The form fields are embedded from external website in Iframe i.e SquareUp
except Hidden field. The Hidden field value is generated on the go when Place Order Button is clicked and appended to that hidden field value using javascript and then customer is redirected to Controller.

My Controller File

```
<?php 


  require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/square/autoload.php');

  class Square_SquarePayment_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
 {

public function processAction(){

        echo 'nonce: '. Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('nonce');

    }
 }


?>
```

I can not get nonce value. The nonce is required in order to call Api and charge the customer.

Comment: No one here to help?